# Start service worker role using management rest api

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-management-api

I am trying to stop / start an Azure Worker role using the Windows scheduler. The action url I used is as follows: `https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<cloudservice-name>/deploymentslots/<deployment-slot>/`. It is secured using a certificate. The response is the following error.

> Http Action - Response from host 'management.core.windows.net':
>   'NotFound' Response Headers: x-ms-servedbyregion: ussouth3
>   Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
>   x-ms-request-id: e1f235c155cf6a00a904a527bc22c77f Cache-Control:
>   no-cache Date: Fri, 15 Jan 2016 19:55:02 GMT Server: 1.0.6198.304
>   (rd_rdfe_stable.160106-1801) Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Body: `ResourceNotFound`The
>   resource service name hostedservices is not
>   supported.

I followed the instructions from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460808.aspx
The raw POST looks like this: POST https://management.core.windows.net/9974e512-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxb846a/services/hostedservices/sblqueueprocessorservice/deployments/c2cdxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6e32/ HTTP/1.1
x-ms-version: 2009-10-01
Content-Type: application/xml
Host: management.core.windows.net
Content-Length: 173

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UpdateDeploymentStatus xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
<Status>Suspended</Status>
</UpdateDeploymentStatus>
```

In addition, the Get Deployment API call works.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri. There is no code as such. It is the url as described above. The service works and I can change the status of it using the 'Stop-AzureService' CmdLet but the Management Service API returns the following : HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
x-ms-servedbyregion: ussouth3
x-ms-request-id: 4ddb785702c76e1fb0d877855e3df609
Date: Mon, 18 Jan 2016 10:25:17 GMT

<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Code>ResourceNotFound</Code><Message>The resource service name hostedservices is not supported.</Message></Error>

Answer (score 0):

It was missing the ?comp=status URI parameter.